# MATLAB Averaging multidimensional arrays in third dimension

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, average

I have a structure called `Task`, which contains the output of preprocessing by the EEG analysing add-on Fieldtrip.

This includes an array called `Task.trial` as well as the header and other output data required by Fieldtrip.  I need to keep this so I can run visualisation code afterwards.

`Task.trial` is a cell array of varying lengths.  Each Participant completes 132 Trials but not all trials pass preprocessing.  This has left a varying number of trials per participant around 120.  For simplicity's sake, Task.trial is a 1x120 cell array.
Each cell of `Task.trial` contains a 66x500 Double, representing EEG channels x frame (at 500 Hz).

I wish to average `Task.trial` across successive trials.  I do not want it to average across frames nor across channels, so I believe I'm looking for mean in the 3rd dimension.  However, the following code:

```
TaskAverage = mean (Task.trial,3);
```

Results in the following error:

> Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
>
> Error in mean (line 115)
>           y = sum(x, dim,
>           flag)/size(x,dim);

I have read numerous questions on here regarding multidimensional arrays and averaging, as well as the matlab help documentation.  I have a very limited understanding of the background of matlab coding, so I cannot figure out how to fix this.  Can anyone explain how to make this work?
My current alternative is to individually add each table of data (120 Trials x So many participants).

Comment: If all of the contents are different sizes, how do you expect to average them?

Comment: Hey, I'm an answering robot! Are you happy?